# Cálculo de média não retorna resultado correto

Tags: javascript, lógica, tipagem

Decidi fazer um programinha para calcular a média. Ele funciona assim:

```
1º Pergunta o número de alunos;
2º Pergunta o nome, e as duas notas; 
3º Calcula a média;
4º Imprime.
```

Porém a função não está retornando o valor de média correto.

```
alunos = []
    notas = []
    medias = []

    function calcmedia(a, b){
        soma = a + b 
        divide = soma / 2
        return divide
    }

    i = prompt("Quanto alunos você deseja verficar? ")
    for(c = 0; c < i; c++){
        alunos[c] = prompt("Qual o seu nome? ")
        notas[c, 0] = prompt("Digite sua 1ª nota: ")
        notas[c, 1] = prompt("Digite sua 2ª nota: ")

        medias[c] = calcmedia(notas[c, 0], notas[c, 1])

        console.log(alunos[c])
        console.log(notas[c, 0])
        console.log(notas[c, 1])
        console.log(medias[c])
        console.log("")
    }
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

Tem vários problemas no código, mas o principal é que não está convertendo um texto para número. Sempre que for usar uma função você deve ler toda documentação dela em detalhes e aprender como usá-la. A `prompt()` diz que retornará uma *string*, portanto não pode fazer contas com ela. Deve usar `parseFloat()` neste caso para converter para um número que possa ser calculado. Note que esta conversão pode dar erro e quebrar a aplicação se for digitado algo que não pode ser convertido, e isto precisa ser tratado, isto fica de exercício para você.

Usei nomes de variáveis mais significativos, simplifiquei o cálculo e eliminei variáveis desnecessárias, além de reduzir o escopo delas. Deixei a função porque pode ter um propósito, mas no código atual é mais simples fazer a conta que criar uma função. Não usei um *array* porque tudo o que não é necessário só cria potencial de problemas. Ele seria útil em outro contexto, nesse é só complicação, o resultado é o mesmo sem ele. O enunciado não fala em *array* ou algo que implica sua necessidade.

```js
function calcMedia(a, b) {
    return (a + b) / 2;
}
var numAlunos = parseFloat(prompt("Quanto alunos você deseja verficar? "));
for (var i = 0; i < numAlunos; i++) {
    var aluno = prompt("Qual o seu nome? ");
    var nota1 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite sua 1ª nota: "));
    var nota2 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite sua 2ª nota: "));
    console.log(aluno);
    console.log(nota1);
    console.log(nota2);
    console.log(calcMedia(nota1, nota2));
    console.log("");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Math/Average.js).

Coloquei `;` e declarei as variáveis explicitamente. Você está no caminho perigosos de tentar fazer o código funcionar sem entender o que está nele, de como ele realmente deve ser escrito.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]